# Does i-- and --i works the same in c++ loops?

Tags: c++

This code gives me the same output in for loop. So, choosing --i or i-- does not really matter here?

Input:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int j=5;
    for(int i=j;i>1;i--){
        std::cout<<i;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    j=5;
    for(int i=j;i>1;--i){
        std::cout<<i;
    }
}
```

Output:
5432
5432

And Does i++ and ++i also works the same in c++?

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and various SO posts. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to find answers to questions yourself before posting here. I can [literally copy and paste the question title into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Does+i--+and+--i+works+the+same+in+c%2B%2B%3F) and get relevant answers at the top.